# how to get current path of .htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess

I want to set the path of 404 error file inside .htaccess file without typing the domain normaly inside it every time when I change the domain.

For example :

This is normal code **`ErrorDocument 404 http://www.example.com/404.php`**

I want to set it to `ErrorDocument 404 404.php`

I mean widthout domain url .

Is there an variable in .htaccess like `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` in php to get domain url ?

Whene I set the 404 code as `ErrorDocument 404 404.php` its show empty page and inside it text like "404.php" only .

thank you for help ^_^ .

Comment: Is there any one can help ?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use in my .htaccess file. Hope it helps.

```
# This redirects browsers that experience a 404 error (Not Found) (and others listed)
# to the file "error.php" located in the same directory as your .htaccess file.
ErrorDocument 400 /error.php
ErrorDocument 401 /error.php
ErrorDocument 403 /error.php
ErrorDocument 404 /error.php
ErrorDocument 500 /error.php
```